# How to make image that is larger than carousel appear the same way on all screens?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

So here I have a carousel:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <!-- Indicators -->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img class="first-slide" src="web-background.jpg" alt="First slide">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>text</h1>
          <p>text</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="pockets.html" role="button">Get me started!</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Although, the image I have for the carosel, is larger than the frame. I was looking into making it look around the same on both desktop and mobile devices.
I have this for CSS:

```
.carousel {
  height: 500px;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}
.carousel-caption {
  z-index: 10;
}
.carousel .item {
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #777;
}
.carousel-inner > .item > img {
  position: absolute;
  top: -70%;
  left: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
}
```

As you can I see I tried a percentage for the `top` in CSS. Other than that I've tried to adjust the `top` in pixels to see if there was some sort of "sweet spot".

Comment: you have `min-width:100%` where I guess you should have `width:100%`. Or is it that your image is more wide than the rest of them? If that's the case you should go `height:100%;overflow:hidden;`. I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly

Comment: @pablito.aven I don't believe you understood correctly. So, the carousel image is larger than the carousel itself. Thus, it appears differently on both desktop and mobile devices. I am trying to have the carousel image be identical (or close to identical) on both desktop and mobile displays.

Comment: Could you add some screenshots, or build a JSFiddle or something like that reproducing your problem?

Comment: @pablito.aven here is a CodePen, just drag the divider over to simulate whatit looks like on a mobile device. [link](http://codepen.io/zanderl/pen/OMqvJo)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
<!-- Indicators -->
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
<li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
</ol>
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
<div class="item active">
<img class="first-slide"    src="http://www.slidesjs.com/examples/standard/img/example-slide-1.jpg" alt="First slide">
<div class="container">
<div class="carousel-caption">
<h1>text</h1>
<p>text</p>
<p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="pockets.html" role="button">Get me started!</a></p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#myCarousel {
width: 100%;
}
.carousel img{
width: 100%;  
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/toolbox3/d5oveknt/1/

Comment: Nothing has changed.

Comment: Make sure to use the fiddle. `#myCarousel` is in place of `.carousel`

Comment: I did, still nothing had changed.

Comment: does the image "web-background.jpg" have a fixed width? If so, delete that from css and inline. The `.carousel img` will adjust the size of the image to the parent div `#myCarousel`

Comment: No it does not have a fixed width, just look at the CSS.

Comment: delete `min-width: 100%` and replace with `width: 100%`. And also delete the heights you have in your css

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103549/discussion-between-htcsml4792-and-toolbox3).